# Разработка библиотек на С++

Tags: c++, linux, библиотеки

Недавно разобрался с функциями, и возникло желание попробовать написать библиотеку, имеются 4 функции и именно их нужно объединить в библиотеку, прошу дать линк на хороший мануал по написанию статических и динамических библиотек.

Comment: Какая платформа?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, среда разработки - Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Погугли: Иванов Н. Программирование в Linux. стр. 40-54.